# How to permanetly fix a mysql error: Data truncated for column with an alter table statement?

Tags: mysql, django

I have a field

```
logo=models.ImageField(upload_to="restaurant_detail/restaurant_detail", help_text = "upload your restaurant logo")
```

this returns an error,`Data truncated for column 'logo' at row 1`

so I go ahead to fix it with this statement

```
alter table my_table modify logo varchar(500)
```

(I increase the characters.)

This works but everytime I reset the database I have to do this again **and** when I try and execute the alter statement above and insert data, it still fails with the `Data truncated for column 'logo' at row 1` error.

How do I permanently fix this without having to alter the table all the time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your field definition to:

```
logo = models.ImageField(max_length=500, upload_to="restaurant_detail/restaurant_detail", help_text="upload your restaurant logo")
```

I added the max_length kwarg which tells Django how many chars the field can store and will cause the database field to be created appropriately.

Comment: after this, is it necessary to regenerate the database?

Comment: Yeah, you would need to either use migrations or otherwise update the database to match the model.