# Data truncate error when using manage.py migrate on fresh django installation

Tags: django, vagrant, python-3.4, mariadb, django-1.9

I have spent hours trying to get a vagrant django development environment running on my Windows 7 machine.

So far I have:

- Used vagrant to create an ubuntu vm
- Installed python 3.4.3
- Installed mariadb 5.5
- Installed django 1.9
- Installed mysql-connector-python 2.1.3
- Created a new DB in mysql

On a fresh django install, when I try to run `python manage.py migrate`, I get the following error:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: sessions, auth, contenttypes, admin
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vagrant/djangoenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mysql/connector/django/base.py", line 177, in _execute_wrapper
    return method(query, args)
  File "/home/vagrant/djangoenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 515, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "/home/vagrant/djangoenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 434, in _handle_result
    self._handle_noresultset(result)
  File "/home/vagrant/djangoenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 404, in _handle_noresultset
    self._warnings[0][1], self._warnings[0][2])
mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 1265: Data truncated for column 'applied' at row 1
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/vagrant/djangoenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 350, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/vagrant/djangoenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 342, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/vagrant/djangoenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/vagrant/djangoenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/vagrant/djangoenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 200, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/vagrant/djangoenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 92, in migrate
    self._migrate_all_forwards(plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/vagrant/djangoenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 121, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/vagrant/djangoenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 204, in apply_migration
    self.recorder.record_applied(migration.app_label, migration.name)
  File "/home/vagrant/djangoenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 73, in record_applied
    self.migration_qs.create(app=app, name=name)
  File "/home/vagrant/djangoenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 401, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/home/vagrant/djangoenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 700, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/home/vagrant/djangoenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 728, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/home/vagrant/djangoenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 812, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/home/vagrant/djangoenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 851, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/home/vagrant/djangoenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 122, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vagrant/djangoenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1039, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/home/vagrant/djangoenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1064, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/vagrant/djangoenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/vagrant/djangoenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/vagrant/djangoenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mysql/connector/django/base.py", line 227, in execute
    return self._execute_wrapper(self.cursor.execute, query, new_args)
  File "/home/vagrant/djangoenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mysql/connector/django/base.py", line 195, in _execute_wrapper
    utils.DatabaseError(err.msg), sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/home/vagrant/djangoenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/vagrant/djangoenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mysql/connector/django/base.py", line 177, in _execute_wrapper
    return method(query, args)
  File "/home/vagrant/djangoenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 515, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "/home/vagrant/djangoenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 434, in _handle_result
    self._handle_noresultset(result)
  File "/home/vagrant/djangoenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 404, in _handle_noresultset
    self._warnings[0][1], self._warnings[0][2])
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: Data truncated for column 'applied' at row 1
```

I couldn't find anything that had that exact error. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Need to see the model for `applied` - likely related to this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16113190/how-to-permanetly-fix-a-mysql-error-data-truncated-for-column-with-an-alter-tabl

Comment: applied is a base django model - how do I view it?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the issue *isn't* how the table or column is defined, so just looking at the table or column definitions isn't going to do you any good*.

In your `[project_name]/settings.py` file make sure that under ...

`DATABASES = { ...`

... the `ENGINE` attribute is set to `django.db.backends.mysql` as opposed to `mysql.connector.django`.

> *Although, you should make sure that the column type for `applied` is `DATETIME(6)`, which shouldn't be a problem since that's the default value Django gives it, so unless you somehow changed it, you should be fine.
>
> The table is `django_migrations` in case you *are* wanting to look up the data type.

Answer (score -1):

If you store 12345678901234567890 into an `INT`, it will be truncated.

If you store 'asdfasdfasdf' into `VARCHAR(5)`, it will be truncated.

Look at your table definition and your data.  *You* can figure this out.